# Unexpected result of greater than or less than comparison on PHP 8

Tags: php, php-8

The below returns `false` on PHP 7 but `true` on PHP 8. Could someone explain why this is happening?

```
var_dump("U0M262" > 100000);
```

Comment: here's the new rfc for php 8 in comparing https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison

Comment: @Kevin so it convert 100000 to string and then do a string comparisons ?

Comment: yes, they changed the behaviour to compare them as strings for non-strict. since the one on the left is non numeric https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034344/3859027

Comment: @Kevin A small correction, there is no "strict" version or mode for the `>` operator, so "non-strict" is meaningless here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does PHP 8 treat 42 == " 42" as true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040819/why-does-php-8-treat-42-42-as-true)

Comment: @NicoHaase I think it's worth keeping both questions open, because they cover different aspects of the same change: that one covers the case that _hasn't_ changed, and talks about _equality comparisons_ (which have the `==` and `===` flavours); this one covers a case that _has_ changed, with _greater than and less than_ (which have only one flavour); and there is also [a question about the common case of _empty_ strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025397/empty-string-comparison-to-zero-gives-different-result-in-php-8-than-in-previous).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no obviously correct result for a comparison between a string and a number. In many languages, it would just give an error; in others, including PHP, the language tries to make sense of it by converting both operands to the same type, but this involves a judgement of which type to "prefer".

---

Historically, PHP has preferred comparing numbers to comparing strings: it treated `"U0M262" > 100000` as `(int)"U0M262" > 100000`. Since `(int)"U0M262"` has no obvious value, it is evaluated as `0`, and the expression becomes `0 > 100000`, which is false.

As of PHP 8, [this behaviour has changed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) and PHP now only uses a numeric comparison for "numeric strings", e.g. `"42"` clearly "looks like" `42`.

Since `"U0M262"` doesn't fit the requirements for a numeric string, `"U0M262" > 100000` is now treated as `"U0M262" > (string)100000`. This does a **byte-wise comparison of the sort order** for the two strings, and finds that since "U" comes after "1" in ASCII (and any ASCII-derived encoding, including UTF-8), the result is true.

---

Because of how ASCII (and compatible encodings such as UTF-8) is arranged:

- A string starting with a control character or space will be "less than" any number
- A string starting with a letter will be "more than" any number
- A string starting with any of "!  "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /" will be "less than" any number
- For a string starting with a digit, you need to look at the individual bytes
- Any other string will be "more than" any number

---

As ever, you can tell PHP which comparison you intended, and get the correct behaviour in all versions, using explicit casts:

```php
var_dump((int)"U0M262" > (int)100000); // bool(false)
var_dump((string)"U0M262" > (string)100000); // bool(true)
```

(Obviously, this makes no sense if you're hard-coding both sides anyway, but assuming one or both is a variable, this is how you'd do it.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation!